# Setting up CPATH in Windows/Eclipse/MinGW

Tags: windows, imagemagick, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have installed Eclipse Neon, MinGW, and got them to work together (after updating my PATH system variable). I am now facing a new issue : I want to use ImageMagick's libraries.

These come in this architecture:

`[PathToImageMagick]\
                    + CORE_RL_Magick++.dll
                    + other .dll files
                    + include\
                              + Magick++.h
                              + Magick++\
                                        + Blob.h (and several other files)
                              + 2 other directories
                    + lib\
                         + CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib 
                         + 2 other .lib files`

Now, I would like to `#include <Magick++.h>` without missing a file dependency.
So far, this is where I've managed to go : I defined a `CPATH` environment variable in my Eclipse Preferences and set it to `[PathToImageMagick]\include`, and a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that I set to `[PathToImageMagick]\lib`.
I did this in my Windows\Prefernces\C/C++\Build\Build Variables panel (it seems Neon has changed a bit the layout in there).

However, I'm still getting `fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory` from Eclipse on my `#include <Magick++.h>`line.

Am I missing something obvious? Am I not using the adequate variable / value ? Am I setting the right variables to the right values in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the culprit!

I was changing the Eclipse\Windows\Preferences settings, and not my project's properties.

Setting the `CPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there fixed my issue.